# can I inherit a class from same file?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am starting in python,

I was trying to write

```
class sample(sample1):
    pass

class sample1:
   pass
```

was trying to inherit class sample1 in class sample. Both class are in same file.

My PyCharm throws error for this inheritance. Can some one helps me to do this?

Comment: `sample1` doesn't exist. Python is interpreted *in order*, and youa re trying to evaluate `sample1` before it is defined. Switch the order of your class definitions.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga